# What is the purpose of the recursive partition function in the merge sort algorithm?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 50

void mergeSort(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high);
void partition(int arr[],int low,int high);

int main(){

    int merge[MAX],i,n;

    printf("Enter the total number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements which to be sort: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         scanf("%d",&merge[i]);
    }

    partition(merge,0,n-1);

    printf("After merge sorting elements are: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         printf("%d ",merge[i]);
    }

   return 0;
}

void partition(int arr[],int low,int high){

    int mid;

    if(low<high){
         mid=(low+high)/2;
         partition(arr,low,mid);
         partition(arr,mid+1,high);   // how it works 
         mergeSort(arr,low,mid,high);
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high){

    int i,m,k,l,temp[MAX];

    l=low;
    i=low;
    m=mid+1;

    while((l<=mid)&&(m<=high)){

         if(arr[l]<=arr[m]){
             temp[i]=arr[l];
             l++;
         }
         else{
             temp[i]=arr[m];
             m++;
         }
         i++;
    }

    if(l>mid){
         for(k=m;k<=high;k++){
             temp[i]=arr[k];
             i++;
         }
    }
    else{
         for(k=l;k<=mid;k++){
             temp[i]=arr[k];
             i++;
         }
    }

    for(k=low;k<=high;k++){
         arr[k]=temp[k];
    }
}
```

How does the recursive `partition` function work in the above program?

Comment: Any problem with this code?

Comment: @user1957167 Please be more specific about what you find confusing?

Answer (score 1):

The recursive portion of `MergeSort` is the `partition` function.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function):

> Recursion (computer science), a procedure or subroutine, implemented in a programming language, whose implementation references itself

`MergeSort` can be broken down into two steps:

1. Divide the unsorted list into *n* sublists, each containing 1 element.
2. Repeatedly merge sublists to produce new sorted sublists until there is only 1 sublist remaining.

Your specific questions involves the `Partition` function:

Essentially, partition is the **divide** portion of the divide-and-conquer algorithm. The **conquer** portion is the recursive call. Finally, the **combine** step is the step of merging the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Mergesort uses a divide and conquer approach.  Here is a [visual representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMerge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg)